# What is [1] in GIT documentation?

Tags: git, documentation

I am start learning GIT and the documentation syntax is confusing.
 What does [1] signify in use cases such as "git-add[1]", or "git-commit[1]"?

It is all over the documentation. On some website pages it appears as parentheses –  "git-init(1)"

What does it represent?

Answer (score 3):

It's the section number of the manual. This convention is general, not limited to Git. See [`man 1 man`](https://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/1/man/):

> […] A section, if provided, will direct `man` to look only in that section of the manual. The default action is to search in all of the available sections, following a pre-defined order and to show only the  first page found, even if page exists in several sections.
>
> The table below shows the section numbers of the manual followed by the types of pages they contain.
>
> 1. Executable programs or shell commands
> 2. System calls (functions provided by the kernel)
> 3. Library calls (functions within program libraries)
> 4. Special files (usually found in `/dev`)
> 5. File formats and conventions eg `/etc/passwd`
> 6. Games
> 7. Miscellaneous (including macro packages and conventions), e.g. `man(7)`, `groff(7)`
> 8. System administration commands (usually only for root)
> 9. Kernel routines [Non standard]

The command to see the manual for `git-init(1)` is therefore `man 1 git-init`. In this case simple `man git-init` works but sometimes you need to explicitly specify the section number you're after. E.g. there is `man(1)` and `man(7)`; `man man` will show you the former, to see the latter you need `man 7 man`.

Comment: Oh – so the numbers in brackets aren't code – they refer to the chapters in the training manual. Thank you.